# Is is possible to get the background color of a folium map from geographical coordinates?

Tags: python, folium

I'm trying to distinguish whether a geographical coordinate is located in water or on land using folium. My idea was to get the background color in folium from a coordinate but I'm not sure how to access it.

I have tried to look through the different plugins that folium has but could not find one that returns a color.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply use a ready-made library that returns whether a coordinate is on land or sea such as https://pypi.org/project/global-land-mask/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the toolkit does not have the resolution that I need.